# find value of an attribute by src

Tags: jquery, html, tags, attr

I need to find a value of an attribute with a certain img src.

```
<div class="ig_gallery_right_img" style="overflow-y: scroll">
  <img src="/corp/homeowner/images/promo/gallery_traditional_3_sm.jpg" 
            swap-section="featured_bath_traditional_1" 
            swap-image="/corp/homeowner/images/promo/gallery_traditional_3.jpg"              
            class="gallery_sidebar_sm" />
  <img src="/corp/homeowner/images/promo/gallery_traditional_5_sm.jpg" 
         swap-section="featured_bath_traditional_2" 
         swap-image="/corp/homeowner/images/promo/gallery_traditional_5.jpg" 
         class="gallery_sidebar_sm" />
</div>
```

I am wondering if there is a way I can get the `swap-section` value by the source of the image.

I have tried `var ig_sec = $('img', url_main_pic).attr('swap-section');`

but that gives me an undefined value.   Any ideas ?

Answer (score 4):

Using the [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```
var ig_sec = $('img[src="'+url_main_pic+'"]').attr('swap-section');
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4RycG/)

---

Also, though your code is fully functional this way, the HTML will not pass the W3C validator. In case that's important for your use-case, you should look into [`data-*`](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) attributes as mentioned by @PSL.

Comment: Might need to handle if src is relative or absolute, or rather if the value in `url_main_pics` is different to the computed value in the `src` property.  Perhaps ensuring `url_main_pic` is relative and using `$('img[src$="' + url_main_pic + '"]')`.

Comment: @Orbling Yes good point, the *attribute equals selector* will only match the exact string in the attribute. I won't make a very complex answer for such a simple question, but there are ways to match in other scenarios. E.g. to match a full URL attribute with a relative one, the [attribute ends with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) can be used. And for the other way around, just strip the domain part from the variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use attribute selector to do a match.

```
 var value=  $('img[src="'+ url +'"]').attr("swap-section");
```

But `swap-section` and `swap-image` are not a valid html attribute so you may want to consider prefixing them with `data-*`

```
<img src="/corp/homeowner/images/promo/gallery_traditional_3_sm.jpg" 
            data-swap-section="featured_bath_traditional_1" 
            data-swap-image="/corp/homeowner/images/promo/gallery_traditional_3.jpg"              
            class="gallery_sidebar_sm" />
  <img src="/corp/homeowner/images/promo/gallery_traditional_5_sm.jpg" 
         data-swap-section="featured_bath_traditional_2" 
         data-swap-image="/corp/homeowner/images/promo/gallery_traditional_5.jpg" 
         class="gallery_sidebar_sm" />
```

And access it with data api

```
 var value=  $('img[src="'+ url +'"]').data("swap-section");
```

If you want a wildcard match then ,

```
var value=  $('img[src*="'+ url +'"]').data("swap-section"); //Remember for more than one match you will get the value of the first one alone. SO you may want to loop through.
```

Comment: Good call.  I was look into that.

Comment: @TonyLombardi You mean the data-* stuff?

Comment: Yes Sir. im taking over someone else's code so that does requiring me to write write a large section of code. But your point is very valid and I will get that going.

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?

```
$('img[src$="gallery_traditional_3_sm.jpg"]').attr('swap-section');
```

From what I gather, using the $ sign in front of src will specify that you only care about the jpg file name at the end.  If you don't use the $ then you need to use the full path of the image (including domain).  Even though you don't put the domain as part of your src when you declare the element, internally the domain is added as part of the attribute, so trying to find the image by using the relative src url will not work and you will retrieve an undefined element.

Comment: Using `[attribute-name$=...]` means that the attribute should "end with" the value after `=`.  This is from regexp syntax, where `$` matches the end of the string.